# fortran in fedora linux

Tags: fedora, software-installation, fortran

I have installed Fedora Linux on my computer. I would like to have the following software installed on it:

```
fortran
gnuplot
xfig
latex
dvips
ghostview
dvipdf
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you learned how to use `yum`?

Comment: if i use yum, do i need an internet connection?

Comment: Have you done any research about the topic of your question? Have you read the basic user documentation for Fedora Linux? The Fedora community is active and has a lot of great guidance available. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Normally I would suggest https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Getting_Started_Guide but they currently have a major network outage and the wiki sites are offline.

Comment: `yum` can use repositories that reside on local storage.  DVDs etc.  But using the internet would probably give you the best coverage of recent rpms. I wouldn't know if you have a dvd with `extras` etc

Answer (score 8):

The syntax you should use to install packages is:

```
dnf install fortran gnuplot xfig latex dvips ghostview dvipdf
```

If you are using an older release, `dnf` won't work. Replace it with `yum` in the previous example.

You can learn more about this yourself at the Fedora [Getting Started Guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Getting_Started_Guide)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you should use to install packages is:

```
sudo dnf install gfortran gnuplot xfig texlive-scheme-basic
```